# Size of vector in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I get counts of elements in vector in c++

```
cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point>> temp;
```

I try this, but it did not give a real size?

```
int counts=Sizeof(temp);
```

I try this also

```
int counts=[temp count];
```

Comment: just use temp.size() . (and read a book on c++, please!)

Comment: This is C++, not Objective-C.

Comment: I don't think there is a `cv::vector`. You should specify clearly which class template you're talking about.

Comment: @juanchopanza... There **is** a `vector` class in `namespace cv`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `temp.size()` for finding out the size of  `Vector`.

Answer (score 3):

That is not objective-c. It is C++ and this vector isn't from the standard. You need to use the .size() function. Just do temp.size().

If you are using openCV check [this documentation on the OpenCV Vectors](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1Vector.html).

Comment: I have edited my answer as well to provide you with more info.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) is the link where you can learn about the C++ STL(Standard Template Library).